# ensure title is fully visible on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a message box with a short message. How can I ensure that title of a message box is not truncated and is fully visible?

Comment: +1 good question, not easy job, maybe not possible to determine lenght in pixels, because toolBar with caption came from Native OS including Font Type & Size

Comment: + 1 A quick test reveals that the message respects the width of a component. So as long as your object is large enough, the whole title will be visible. Problem is to determine the width of the title + any other offsets (like the close button which consumes some space)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips to calculate the width of a string within a graphics context:

http://www.ubeedoo.com/home?user=JavierArroyo&channel=TechTips-Java&buzzid=7699520895746755172

Hope it helps.